# How to yank from the command line

Tags: vim, vi

I wonder if it is possible to yank something I have written in the command line from vim so I can later paste it again.

This would be particularly useful because I often try out search/replace patterns by just searching for them first and - if they match what I need - I would like to be able to just copy that searched expression from the command line and use it in my search/replace function.

I already know that you can paste into the command window by using `<ctrl-r><buffer>` and I just wonder if there is a command similar to this that will yank my whole command window.

Comment: Vim question are generally on topic. There has been a lot of discussion about it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su for example it's a good one.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use the [command line window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#q%3a). Use <kbd>q</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> to open it. Then you can navigate the window as an ordinary one and yank what you want to yank.

Comment: Ah finally I know what that window is - I sometimes opened it by accident when trying to quit vim.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I remember the first times it happened to me and I was like "What the hell is that?" :)

Comment: You can also use `q/` to access the search history in a similar way. This is useful when you are trying to adjust/refine a search pattern.

Answer (score 17):

Vim stores the most recently entered command in the `:` register and the most recently searched expression in the `/` register. Since you already know how to paste into the command window you can simply type `<Ctrl-R>/` to paste in whatever you last searched for.

Comment: To add to this, vim is smart enough to use the contents of the `/` register if you simply leave out the search pattern in a `:substitute` command.  For instance if you've searched for `foo`, then do `:s//bar` vim will replace `foo` with `bar` without any copying or pasting necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Other ways:

- if the `'cedit'` option hasn't been overridden hit CTRL-F while entering the command line. Then you have access to a subset of normal mode for editing it. `:help 'cedit'`
- If you need the last command line entered you can use `:put :` (variant of David Brown's answer and relying on the colon register containing the last command).